# Lambda with itertools not working

Tags: python, lambda

I want to create a Cartesian product and choose the tuples from second and third position which are equal or differ only by 1

```
import itertools

a = [(1,4), (2,2), (3,9),(7,4),(5,4)];

a1 = ( list(itertools.product(*a)))

print (a1)
i=a1[1]
k=a1[2]


new_list = list(filter(lambda i,k: (i-k <= 1) , a1))
print (my_list)
```

But result is

```
[(1, 2, 3, 7, 5), (1, 2, 3, 7, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 4), (1, 2, 9, 7, 5), (1, 2, 9, 7, 4), (1, 2, 9, 4, 5), (1, 2, 9, 4, 4), (1, 2, 3, 7, 5), (1, 2, 3, 7, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 4), (1, 2, 9, 7, 5), (1, 2, 9, 7, 4), (1, 2, 9, 4, 5), (1, 2, 9, 4, 4), (4, 2, 3, 7, 5), (4, 2, 3, 7, 4), (4, 2, 3, 4, 5), (4, 2, 3, 4, 4), (4, 2, 9, 7, 5), (4, 2, 9, 7, 4), (4, 2, 9, 4, 5), (4, 2, 9, 4, 4), (4, 2, 3, 7, 5), (4, 2, 3, 7, 4), (4, 2, 3, 4, 5), (4, 2, 3, 4, 4), (4, 2, 9, 7, 5), (4, 2, 9, 7, 4), (4, 2, 9, 4, 5), (4, 2, 9, 4, 4)]


    new_list = list(filter(lambda i,k: (i-k <= 1) , a1))
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'
```

What is wrong with my lambda?

Comment: You set `my_list` to an empty list and then you filter that. If you start with nothing, it doesn't matter what you filter out of it, you will still just have nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools
a =[(1,4),(2,2),(3,9),(7,4),(5,4)]
b = itertools.product(*a)
c = filter(lambda x: abs(x[1]-x[2])<=1, b)
print(c)
```

gives (edited for visibility)

```
[(1, 2, 3, 7, 5), 
 (1, 2, 3, 7, 4), 
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 4), 
 (1, 2, 3, 7, 5), 
 (1, 2, 3, 7, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 4),
 (4, 2, 3, 7, 5), 
 (4, 2, 3, 7, 4), 
 (4, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
 (4, 2, 3, 4, 4), 
 (4, 2, 3, 7, 5), 
 (4, 2, 3, 7, 4), 
 (4, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
 (4, 2, 3, 4, 4)]
```